# open system call - Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Trying to open tty port using open system call. HOw do i know if this port is being used by another application in case the open system call returns -1?

DO not find error codes for the same.

Comment: To find the actual error code, you should check `errno` if `open()` returns `-1`.  That should give you more insight about the error... though I don't think it's going to be able to tell you if it's under use already.

Comment: You cannot find out if a file is open by another application in standard C. You can use system utilities (lsof), or solutions specific to your case (advisory file locks in case all processes in question use them).

Answer (score 0):

a call to `open()` won't give you an error if the file is already open.

Howerver, you can try to analyze the output of the linux `lsof`command:

`lsof /dev/ttyS0`

It will return information about the processes that opened the given file (in this case: /dev/ttyS0).

*(I've tested this a few times so I'm not sure about it, but `lsof` seems to return **0** if the file is opened by a process and return **1** if no process has opened it. This could be an indication, however I would suggest you really analyze the output of the command itself)*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strcing.h>

int main() 
{
    if(open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR))
        printf("errno = %s\n", strerror(errno));

    return errno;
}
```

see this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-errnovariable/) in order to figure out what the error code is.